# Моргают страницы в браузере

Tags: django, webbrowser

У меня есть маленькое приложение на Django. Оно работает. Но на доли секунды появляется белый фон при нажатии на ссылки. В браузере Firefox такого нет а в Chromium and Opera такое проявляется но только в данном приложении. Я так понимаю что это связанно с кэшированием. Есть какое-нибудь решение чтоб это сиправить?
[Здесь моё приложение.](http://mikeru.pythonanywhere.com/)

Comment: А где там собственно ссылки?

Comment: Ага, вы правы. Не ссылки а кнопки.

Comment: У меня в фоксе, фон становится белым на долю секунды, потом он "условно синий", потом диалог, после закрытия наоборот "синий" белый, потом нормальная страница. Но белая появляется на 0,1 секунды её почти не видно.

Comment: Я не нашёл, наверно глюк в начале анимации. Поставьте по умолчанию на div с анимацией прозрачный или другой цвет. Возможно прозрачность ставится позже чем добавление div-а.